# Show that $ \int_{0}^{n\pi} (1 + x^3\sin^2(x))^{-1}\,\mathrm dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\pi} (1 + (k\pi + x)^3\sin^2(x))^{-1}\,\mathrm dx $

Tags: analysis

1.Show that for all $a > 0$

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi} (1 + a\sin^2(x))^{-1} \mathrm{d}x = 2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  (1 + a\sin^2(x))^{-1}\mathrm{d}x $$

2. Show that for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}^* $

$$ \int_{0}^{n\pi} (1 + x^3\sin^2(x))^{-1} \mathrm{d}x = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\pi}  (1 + (k\pi + x)^3\sin^2(x))^{-1}\mathrm{d}x $$

3. Show that $$ \int_{0}^{\infty}  (1 + x^3\sin^2(x))^{-1}\mathrm{d}x$$  converges.

---

1. $$ \int_{0}^{\pi} (1 + a\sin^2(x))^{-1} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1 + a\sin^2(x))^{-1} \mathrm{d}x + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} (1 + a\sin^2(x))^{-1} \mathrm{d}x $$

I don't see how to show that $\int_{0}^{\pi} (1 + a\sin^2(x))^{-1} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} (1 + a\sin^2(x))^{-1}\mathrm{d}x $

2. I'm stuck on this one.
3. I need to show that $ \int_{0}^{\pi}  (1 + (k\pi + x)^3\sin^2(x))^{-1}\mathrm{d}x $ converges, I don't know how. Thank you for your help.

Comment: HINT: graph the function $\sin^2 x$ in $[0,\pi]$, and the statement $$\int_{0}^{\pi} (1 + a\sin^2(x))^{-1} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} (1 + a\sin^2(x))^{-1}\mathrm{d}x$$ is not true.

Comment: @Masacroso I don't see how to use your hint. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try the change of variables $u=\pi-x$.
2. Properly cut the integral into $n$ parts and use a change of variables on each part.
3. We need to control the generic term of the series

$$\int_0^\pi (1+(k\pi+x)^3 \sin^2(x))^{-1} \mathrm{d}x \leq \int_0^\pi (1+(k\pi)^3 \sin^2(x))^{-1} \mathrm{d}x.
$$

**Solution 1 :** Use the change of variable $u=\tan{x}$ to show that $$\int_0^{\pi/2} (1+a\sin^2{x})^{-1} \mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1+a}}.$$

**Solution 2 :** Use the inequality $\sin{x}\geq (2/\pi)x$ for $0\leq x \leq \pi/2$ to show that

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} (1+a\sin^2{x})^{-1} \mathrm{d}x \leq \frac{\pi^2}{4\sqrt{a}}.$$

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer to the second question? Thank you.

Comment: One has $\int_0^{n\pi} f(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^\pi f(x)\mathrm{d}x + \int_\pi^{2\pi} f(x) \mathrm{d}x + \dotsb + \int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi} f(x) \mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: How to use the change of variable here?

Comment: You need to show that

$$
\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} (1+x^3\sin^2{x})^{-1} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{\pi} (1+(k\pi+x)^3\sin^2{x})^{-1} \mathrm{d}x.
$$
You should be able to guess the right change of variable in this integral.

Comment: Use $u = k\pi - x$, right?

Comment: No, it should be $u=x-k\pi$.

Comment: I added some hints for the third question.

Comment: Thank you for your help.